# A Links redirecting to directory error but files in directory exist

Tags: javascript, html

i made a navigation bar and somehow my a link elements inside of it are not redirecting me to the given files. This is made in replit.

Code:

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="./frontend/features.html">Features</a>
  <a href="./frontend/pricing.html">Pricing</a>
  <a href="./frontend/contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="./frontend/">Login</a>
</nav>
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile("./index.html", { root: "./frontend" });
  console.log("ooga booga")
});

app.listen(8080)
```

Picture of directory:

[image: directory]

I've tried multiple ways of getting the frontend folder:

```
./frontend/
```

```
/frontend/
```

```
frontend/
```

I expected myself being able to click on the a element buttons and the file being shown

I get an error that reads: `Cannot GET /frontend/features.html`

Comment: since the `root` is `frontend`, you wouldn't need that in the url - so `./contact.html` or `contact.html`?

Comment: this also doesnt work, i just tried both methods you mentioned. @JaromandaX

Comment: wouldn't `app.get('/', function(req,res) { res.sendFile("./index.html"` result in all `get` requests being sent `index.html`?

Comment: that is the default landing page, within the HTML of that landing page, I'm trying to redirect to the clicked navbar button with only the <a> elements in each webpage

Comment: yes, and your server is sending `index.html` for every request, because that's what you told it to do - `res.sendFile("./index.html"` ... that's what you're sending for every GET request

Comment: see [*documentation*](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for how to use expressjs with static files

Answer (score 1):

A link beginning with `.` is a relative link, which is relative to the *current file*.  The current file, `index.html`, already being in the `frontend` folder can link to other pages *relative* to it in the same directory without needing to reference that directory.

To link the features page from the index page it would be

```
<a href="./features.html">Features</a>
```

Comment: this unfortunately doesnt work. i just changed what you've provided and it still provides the same error @yoduh